# Создание выпадающего списка с возможностью выбора нескольких элементов в thymeleaf

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли, и если можно то как, написать код в thymeleaf для выпадающего списка ролей(UserCriteria.roles) в котором можно будет выбирать несколько этих ролей.

Имеется следующий код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
            <input id="showFilters" type="button" class="btn btn-default" th:value="#{StudentController.filters}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" hidden="hidden" id="searchForm">
        <form id="searchForm">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="user" type="com.jborned.vverh.service.dto.UserDTO"*/-->
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="userRole" type="com.jborned.vverh.db.model.UserRole"*/-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                        <input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{UserController.name}"
                               name="firstName" th:value="${userCriteria.firstName}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{UserController.surname}"
                               name="lastName" th:value="${userCriteria.lastName}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3  form-group">
                        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{UserController.mail}"
                               name="email" th:value="${userCriteria.email}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3  form-group">
                            <select name="enabled" id="enabled_input" class="form-control">
                                <option value="true" th:selected="${userCriteria.enabled == true}" th:text="#{yes}"></option>
                                <option value="false" th:selected="${userCriteria.enabled == false}" th:text="#{no}"></option>
                                <option value="" th:selected="${userCriteria.enabled == null}" th:text="#{soso}"></option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                            <input type="submit" style="margin-right: 10px" class="btn btn-default filters" th:value="#{apply}"/>
                            <input id="clearButton" type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn-primary" th:value="#{clear}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class UserCriteria implements SearchCriteria {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Boolean enabled = true;
    private Set<UserRole> roles; //todo
}
```

.

```
@Controller
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(USERS)
public class UserController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = LISTING)
    public String userListing(@ModelAttribute("userCriteria") UserCriteria userCriteria, Pageable pageable,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String successAddUser,
                              Model model) {
        Page<UserListingDTO> users = userService.getAllUsersForListing(pageable, userCriteria);
        model.addAttribute("userListing", users);

        if (successAddUser != null) {
            model.addAttribute("successAddUser", true);
        }

        return "user/users";
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь добавить подобное окно ниже уже существующих, но пока никак не выходит.

Comment: Загрузить список можно селектом.

Comment: Написал селект, ругается на th:selected в блоке

<option 
    th:value="COUCH"
    th:selected="${userCriteria.roles.equals('COUCH')}"
    th:text="#{user.couch}">
 </option>